Expo project FetchError: unable to verify the first certificate
In my React Native Expo project when I run npx expo start the logs are reaching the point 'Starting Metro Bundler' and then it throws an error - 'FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/sdks/49.0.0/native-modules failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (..\path_to_project\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1501:11)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)'.
I can open the link from the error message in the browser.
Couple of days ago everything was fine, now the only way is to start the project offline with npx expo start --offline but still can't update or build the app.
I'm using Expo SDK 49, RN 0.72.6 and NodeJS 16 (also tried with Node 18 and 20 with no success).
Any help will be appreciated!

I found a solution in this comment. It turns out to be an issue with the antivirus program - Eset in my case. But still the question - how was all fine and one day 'unable to verify the first certificate'?

Please edit your question, it's not an answer
